# WPF Material Design ListView Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding, material-design

i am using material design to my project ... the problem is the default theme of material design ListView is transparent and i cannot change the background color simply by change the property background to color ... so i add style to the listview so i override to the theme. the problem is that my data binding in default material design listview is working but when i add style to list view data binding does not work okay and show me the object name in the list.

ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="lst" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="335,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="259" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="#" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="data" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding data}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

even i tried [Material Design In XAML override style not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498540/material-design-in-xaml-override-style-not-working) and i got same result.

when the material design is not added to the project, the above listview xaml works okay. so i am confused ... is that any bug or issue within material design or i need to try another way for binding (note: i also tried binding by items.resource and datacontext also)

Comment: [This](https://gitter.im/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) is a community of MaterialDesignInXAML users. You can ask here if you want. Usually someone replies within 12 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply a `Background` to a transparent `ListView`, you could just put it in a `Panel`:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <ListView x:Name="lst" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="335,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="259" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="#" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="data" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding data}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: i thought of similar work around like using white rectangle or grid or some thing .... but it is not make sense i cannot do it as it should be ... and proper way like style makes it not working with binding .. i wonder to know its my coding problem or material design ? :|

Comment: It's a material design theming thing. The other option would be to modify the templates or use an ItemContainerStyle if you want to change the background of the items. But why bother with this when there is a simpler solution?

Comment: yeah ... thanks @mm8 for reply ... i go with white grid ... not a big deal .... i tried ItemContainerStyle...  but nothing changed ....:(

Comment: It works if you set the Background property of the container. But this doesn't change the background of the entire ListView.