# How to override ComboBox ToggleButton from Material Design for XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm new in WPF.
I have an issue with overriding [MaterialDesignComboBoxToggleButton](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ComboBox.xaml)
style. I wanna to replace "Template" setter with own, but my content from control template always ignores. Why this occurred? With other styles i haven't this problem.

Bellow code demonstrates what i need.

**Overriedes.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ComboBox.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBoxToggleButton}" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <TextBlock FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold">$$</TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="Wpf.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         
         xmlns:local="clr-Wpf" xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <materialDesign:CustomColorTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="#FFD8E1FF" SecondaryColor="#FFD8E1FF" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Overrides.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the same resource key to your custom style like this:

```xml
<Style 
    x:Key="MaterialDesignComboBoxToggleButton"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBoxToggleButton}" 
    TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <TextBlock FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold">$$</TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and you don't need to add resources like this in `Overrides.xaml` file:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ComboBox.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

because the MDIX resources already included by [`MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml`](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml) that you added in `App.xaml` file.

Comment: I've already tried this case, but, unfortunately, doesn't work. My snippets followed the answer for similar question [override-style-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498540/material-design-in-xaml-override-style-not-working) and this case for this style also doesn't work. No idea what actually happening. Thanks for the answer

Comment: agree, it's works, but for one case usage: `<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBoxToggleButton}" />`. But what about a toggle button in combobox and without style referencing?

Comment: it seems that dependent style like MaterialDesignComboBoxToggleButton resolves before merging Resource Dictionary with overriding for this style, so my changes not applied. Therefore need to override whole MaterialDesignCombobox style? If so, this forces me to download source code and make into it needed changes :)

Comment: @IvanBeschetnikov Did you find other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

In my case override style in window not working  ,but when I tried in App.xml then it works. I changed the style for toggle button by another style .  the code is :

```
  <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/IG/IG.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/IG/IG.MSControls.Toolkit.Implicit.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Indigo.xaml" />

            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"                  
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0F0F4B" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF73ADDE" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF150404" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>




        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```